# Angular2 warnings when exporting interfaces from own file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have about 5 interfaces that I am exporting and needing to use across multiple components. These interfaces are all related as each of them include / reference one of the others as an array of data.

Here is an example:

```
export interface ParentData {
    UIVersion: number;
    VersionID: number;
    Rule: RuleData[];
}

export interface RuleData {
    RuleParentID: number;
    RuleVersionID: number;
    MappedValue: number;
    ProcessingOrder: number;
    KeyID: number;
    Value: string;
    IsRuleRetired: boolean;
    UserImpactCount: number;
    Attribute: AttributeData[];
}

export interface AttributeData {
    AttributeID: number;
    AttributeName: string;
    OperatorID: number;
    OperatorName: string;
    SQLOperator: string;
    AttributeValue: ValueData[];
}

export interface ValueData {
    RuleDetailID?: number;
    AttrValue: number;
    Value: string;
    IsValueRetired: boolean
}
```

I created an interface file where I included all of these and then imported them into my components that use them.

When doing this, I get errors / failure to compile saying that they are missing or have no exported member.

However, if I include all 5 of them like the example in each component individually, it compiles, just throws warnings such as `"export 'ValueData' was not found in './../../../example.component`.

Are there any issues with exporting interfaces that reference each other being contained in their own file and imported into the component?

**UPDATE:**

I restarted the server after getting all of the component based interfaces removed and replaced by the import file. It compiled successfully, however, I get a warning per interface that is including an array of another interface.

`export 'ValueData' was not found in 
 export 'AttributeData' was not found in
 export 'RuleData' was not found in`

I suppose this could be ignored for now assuming the definitions are actually there and typescript is just being weird..

**UPDATE 2:**

These warnings may be because I am not initializing the array?

```
@Input() parentRuleData: RuleData; // Rules Data

ngOnInit() {
    this.ruleFormGroup = this.toFormGroup(this.parentRuleData);
}   

private toFormGroup(data: RuleData) {
    const formGroup = this._fb.group({
        RuleParentID: [ data.RuleParentID ],
        RuleVersionID: [ data.RuleVersionID ],
        MappedValue: [ data.MappedValue],
        ProcessingOrder: [ data.ProcessingOrder ],
        KeyID: [data.KeyID ],
        Value: [data.Value],
        IsRuleRetired: [data.IsRuleRetired],
        UserImpactCount: [data.UserImpactCount]
    });

    return formGroup;
}
```

However, if I change the `Input` to `@Input() parentRuleData: RuleData[] = [];` as well as the `toFormGroup(data: RuleData)` to `toFormGroup(data: RuleData[])`, the `ngOnInit` and `toFormGroup` methods throw errors:

```
Argument of type 'RuleData[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RuleData'.
```

Comment: I do this all the time and don't get warnings. How are you including them in `example.component` and what version of `tsc` are you running?

Comment: @msanford - My import looks like `import { ParentData, RuleData, ValueData, AttributeData } from '../../../../definitions/maps.interface'`. Typescript is at `~2.2.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your last interface you are missing `semicolon`

```
export interface ValueData {
    RuleDetailID?: number;
    AttrValue: number;
    Value: string;
    IsValueRetired: boolean; <----
}
```

Additionally, seems like known issue

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2034

Comment: I added this, removed all the component based exports and adding the import back in to this file resulting in the same error. It fails to compile and tells me that the component it self has no exported member called `RuleData`.

Comment: Thanks for the issue link. For the time being, I had to do `@Input() parentRuleData: RuleData | null` which seems to have suppressed the warnings. Hopefully that will be fixed soon but you have identified the issue.